# Assertion error when using SolvePnP in OpenCv

Tags: opencv, opencv-solvepnp

I am trying to find the calibration from
I was following the type of inputs described [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/1073/what-format-does-cv2solvepnp-use-for-points-in-python/?sort=votes), but i am having this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-6amqbhlx/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp:753: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) ) && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F)) in function 'solvePnPGeneric'
```

Example [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WprQw.png):

Any hints where this error might be coming from?